# extract year_month from a date column along with other columns in a sql table

Tags: sql, datetime, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, extract

I have a sql table with multiple fields including (but not limited to the following): member_id, visit_date (in datetime format eg: 2016-01-01), visit_yr_qtr (as string, eg: 2016_Q1), purchase_item (ID number), and item_price (in US dollars).

I would like to extract these fields, but also include year_month (2016- January or 2016-01)as a new field in the output. This is what I tried to do but have not been successful:

```
          select member_id, visit_date, visit_yr_qtr, purchase_item, item_price, 
          EXTRACT(year_month, visit_date)
          FROM <table name>
```

Can somebody suggest a way to extract year_month from the visit_date column in the output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax for [EXTRACT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/extract.html) is

> EXTRACT( <date_or_time_part> FROM <date_or_time_expr> )

And among the `<date_or_time_part>` are `year` and `month`

So to get the `yearmonth` you need 2 extracts.

```
CONCAT(EXTRACT(year FROM visit_date),'-', LPAD(EXTRACT(month FROM visit_date), 2, 0))
```

A shorter method is to use [TO_CHAR](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/to_char.html) with a [format](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-conversion.html#label-date-time-format-conversion).

```
TO_CHAR(visit_date,'YYYY-MM')
```

Comment: Works beautifully Luk! Thank you.

Comment: Thanks. Btw, I've added an [LPAD](https://dwgeek.com/snowflake-pad-zeros-lpad-and-rpad-with-examples.html/) to add a leading 0 to months under 10.

Comment: smirk +1 for even more smaller answer! well played, and most sensible..

Answer (score 2):

Luk's answer is good, you can use the [YEAR and MONTH](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/year.html) shortcut functions, and use the [`||` concat](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/concat.html) token to make it all smaller, and [LPAD](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/lpad.html):

```
SELECT 
    '2016-01-01'::date as visit_date,
    CONCAT(EXTRACT(year FROM visit_date),'-', LPAD(EXTRACT(month FROM visit_date), 2, 0)) as way_1,
    year(visit_date) || '-' || month(visit_date) as way2,
    year(visit_date) || '-' || lpad(month(visit_date),2,'0') as way2_padded;
```

giving:

| VISIT_DATE | WAY_1 | WAY2 | WAY2_PADDED |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2016-01-01 | 2016-01 | 2016-1 | 2016-01 |

Comment: I like the pipe operator approach as a way to avoiding parentheses in a long, complex sql query. Thank you!